# How to use th SUM function to return the values from sqlite DB in android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my application, store the amount details of company in my sq lite DB.For example om my first position of DB in name column-company 1,total column - 400,second position of DB in name column-company 2,total column - 800,third position of DB in name column-company 1,total column - 500.how Sum the company 1 details only to return the total amount.

My main coding is,

```
String str = db.company_amount("Company 1");
Log.v("Total", ""+str);
```

My DB coding is,

```
String company_amount(String name){

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

String s = "";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(KEY_AMOUNT) FROM TABLE_BILL_DETAILS WHERE = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(name)});

if (cursor != null) {

    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        s = cursor.getString(1);
        return cursor.getString(1);
    }
    cursor.close();

}

return s;
}
```

It shows some error,I don't know how to return the values.Can any one know please help me to solve this problem.

My Logcat Error

```
04-25 14:54:06.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2776): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 14:54:06.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2776): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

ComponentInfo{invoicebill.details/invoicebill.details.Total_company_details}:                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT SUM(KEY_AMOUNT) FROM TABLE_BILL_DETAILS WHERE = ?
```

Comment: What is that "some error"? Why you people avoid showing this error messages? This one of the most important pieces in your questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();    
String sql = "SELECT SUM(KEY_AMOUNT) FROM TABLE_BILL_DETAILS WHERE name = ?";
long sum = android.database.DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, sql, new String[]{name});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE = ?
```

This is incorrect SQL syntax. You forgot to specify which field you're comparing with the argument. I guess it's *name* or something similar, so correct syntax would be something like:

```
WHERE name = ?
```

Comment: that should be the main problem.  also im not getting that last lines. you simply double-code it there.  also, what does getString(1) get you?

Answer (score 1):

you can use to get details using id like this.

```
public int getTotalOfAmount(int id) { 

    odb = dbh.getReadableDatabase(); 

    Cursor c = odb.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + KEY_AMOUNT + ") FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " = " + id, null); 

    c.moveToFirst(); 
    int i = c.getInt(0); 
    c.close(); 
    return i;

}
```

.

Comment: I didn't get you. What you Coming to say in this answer.

Comment: Sorry yugesh,i do some mistake i recorrect that pls check it you have to sum the column using like this query